# Adding Buttons to Windows XP Explorer (Shell-Extension?)

Tags: windows-xp, windows-explorer, toolbar, shell-extensions

I would like to add some extra buttons to the Windows XP Explorer toolbar (specifically, but not limited to file-selection such as *Select-All* and *Invert-Selection*). Unfortunately while they are default commands in Explorer, they are not included in the built-in list of toolbar buttons.

Ironically, Windows 7 which has no toolbar at all can have these functions added via Classic Shell, but from what I can tell, CS is not compatible with XP. [StExBar](http://tools.tortoisesvn.net/StExBar.html) is good, but it does not have those specific commands.

Does anyone know of a shell-extension that can allow a user to add some custom buttons to the Explorer toolbar (or at least add buttons for the built-in Explorer commands)?